# Why does my Android app break when I install Mercado Pago Checkout using Maven?

Tags: android, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

Mercado pago SDK android

I want to include the Mercado Pago Checkout in my android app but when I want to add into my dependencies

`implementation "com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.53.2"`

I have to add this

`maven { setUrl 'https://artifacts.mercadolibre.com/repository/android-releases/' }`

My problem is that when I install the Mercado Pago checkout like this, the app is installed correctly but it breaks. My app does not open

Any help?

I tried everything but it still happening